# Did Paul Orberson make $1,000,000/month for 44 months?

Tags: personal-finance

I was pitched a multi-level marketing scheme a couple years ago and have been fascinated ever since (as in, the mathematics and how to protect others, not as in a participant). This particular one is called [Fortune Hi-Tech Marketing](http://www.fhtm.net) (FHTM). In business presentations (like [this one around 2:30](http://thereelfhtm.net/v121.aspx)) and online material, I've heard that FHTM's founder, Paul Orberson, was involved in a network marketing company previously in his life, and that this is what inspired him to create FHTM.

The company was called Excel Communications, and Orberson is said to have shattered sales records left and right and earned more money in less time than anyone in the industry.

Specifically, [claims are made](http://donttripoveryourbrain.blogspot.com/2009/03/paul-orberson-and-excel.html) that he made over $1,000,000 USD per month for 44 months straight before leaving the company. (USA Today has him saying $100,000/month [in one of their articles](http://www.usatoday.com/money/companies/2010-10-15-multilevelmarketing15_ST2_N.htm), though there's no stipulation that this was the maximum).

**Is there any verification for Paul Orberson's sales record with Excel Communication?**

Comment: Yes you can get rich by starting a MLM.  You may be able to get rich if you get in early and build a big network under you though your upline generally makes more than you can.  These are basically legal [pyramid schemes](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/042104.asp#axzz1hqEKb3uu).  Eventually most of these die out as the profits become to thin and the bottom collapses.  You can also have $1m income but $0 profits.  But if the guy selling it is saying he is already making $1m a month its probably to late to get in and have a real chance to match him.

Comment: @chad: We're on the same page. I studied FHTM and wrote a fairly lengthy mathematical analysis of how it works based on their payoffs. It is, in my opinion, what you claim: a "legal" pyramid scheme in which those coming in later just feed those already at the top (though several states have issued cease and desist orders...). The question remains... did Paul Orberson have the fantastic success they like to claim while he was at Excel? In huge hotel recruiting talks, they cite Paul's earnings as a way to solicit trust in the business since an "expert" started it...

Comment: Its part of the "Lotto" effect "George in Pocatello won 200 million and you could too..." The difference is the chances are the prize pool has probably been mostly claimed. And while you may have the potential to make that much realistically the chances are probably less for you than they were for him and his original odds were slim.  You are not going to get Bill Gates rich by going into Microsoft today.  You get Bill Gates rich by getting in early.  What they say may well be true.  But what they are implying(that you can do it too) is at best unlikely.

Comment: For the record - 20 years ago I got involved with a MLM selling books.  It lasted for a year but in the end I was broke, my car was busted, and the company and its big promises cast me aside despite the fact that I had over 250k in sales the year before a small team of my own and a promise a month earlier that I was on my way and they would do what it took to see me succeed.  The worst part was I watched them do it to a half dozen other people and never realized what was actually going on.  They use "Motivational" meetings to distract you from reality.

Comment: If all you have is four comments, 3 from the same person then you don't have much of an argument that it doesn't work right?

Comment: @Anthony: Read the question more carefully. The question of whether MLM works or not is moot (there's plenty of careful analysis out there to show who the winners and losers are.) The question is if there is any evidence that this particular individual made as much as is claimed.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Correct. Paul Orberson started FHTM, and it in their advertising they tout that he was the most successful MLM-er who has ever existed (when he was with Excel). I'm wondering if there is accessible evidence to support this.

Comment: Looks like the FTC doesn't agree with his business. http://www.kentucky.com/2013/01/28/2493747/federal-state-officials-send-workers.html